# How to generate sequence of characters starting from A00001 in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sequence

I a writing an sql function which generates a sequence of numbers each time.
For example : `AA00001`, `AA00002` till `AA99999`, then start with `AB00001`.

I know sequence method in SQL server, but it only accept numbers.

How to achieve this? Can anybody help on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the goal of this sequence? Is it to act as a primary key? Are you content with gaps in the value, just like a `SEQUENCE`/`IDENTITY`? Is this something you expect to need to generate in multiple places (like when you use a `SEQUENCE`) or is it specific for a single table (like an `IDENTITY`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has a few assumptions, as my comment got no response.

Firstly, I'm going to assume you are happy with gaps, like an `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE`. In regards in implementing it like a `SEQUENCE` or `IDENTITY` the solution I use here is actually the same as I use a `PERSISTED` computed column here to define the value. This means you'll need an `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE` column in your table as well.

This solution is actually pretty simple. For the last 5 characters, you just need the modulo of `100000`. For the *second* character you need to integer division of the value divided by `100000` followed by getting the module of 26, and for the first character it's the value divided by `100000` and then by `26`.

This will work for any given value between `0` (`'AA00000'`) and `67599999` (`'ZZ99999'`).

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (I int IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT chk_I_ValidRange CHECK (I >= 1 AND I <= 67599999),
                            YourSequence AS CONCAT(CHAR((I / 100000 / 26)+65),CHAR(((I / 100000)%26)+65),RIGHT(CONCAT('00000',I % 100000),5)) PERSISTED);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
DEFAULT VALUES;
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
DEFAULT VALUES;
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.YourTable ON;

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(I)
VALUES(7163742),
      (3624),
      (67599999);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.YourTable OFF;
GO

SELECT *
FROM  dbo.YourTable;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5HBbBlht)

Comment: Note this will generate a zero number (e.g. AB00000). The question is not clear but I understood the ask to be a function similar to SQL 2022 `GENERATE_SERIES` but with alpha characters for the first 2 positions.

Comment: Good point, @DanGuzman , I didn't take the starting at 00001 into account (and in truth, I feel like it would be a flaw to do that)

Answer (score 1):

Extending on @Larnu 's answer, below is an example function that generates an alphanumeric series using a CTE.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GenerateSequence(@Count int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    WITH 
         t10 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
        ,numbers AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS num FROM t10 AS a CROSS JOIN t10 AS b CROSS JOIN t10 AS c CROSS JOIN t10 AS d CROSS JOIN t10 AS e)
    SELECT
        CONCAT(
              CHAR(((num-1) / (99999*26)) % 26 + 65)
            , CHAR(((num-1) / 99999) % 26 + 65)
            , RIGHT('0000' + CAST((num-1) % 99999 + 1 AS varchar(5)), 5)) AS SequenceValue
    FROM numbers
    WHERE
        num <= @Count
        AND num <= 67599324 --avoid rollover
);
GO
```

In Azure SQL Database and SQL Server 2022+, `GENERATE_SERIES` may be leveraged to generate the series of numbers, avoiding the need for a CTE to do same.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GenerateSequence(@Count int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT
        CONCAT(
              CHAR(((value-1) / (99999*26)) % 26 + 65)
            , CHAR(((value-1) / 99999) % 26 + 65)
            , RIGHT('0000' + CAST((value-1) % 99999 + 1 AS varchar(5)), 5)) AS SequenceValue
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, @Count)
    WHERE
        value <= @Count
        AND value <= 67599324 --avoid rollover
);
GO
```